# Restrict browser not to auto populate email and password

Tags: php

I have a login form as below:

```
<form name="checkform" action="example.php">
   <input type="text" id="c_email" name="c_email" placeholder="EMail here">
   <input type="text" id="c_epass" name="c_epass" placeholder="Password here">
   <input type="submit" id="c_sub">
</form>
```

Now when i use this form to Login and then browser ask to save password. I clicked yes and those are saved in browser. But i do not want to auto populate these details everytime i open the page to login.

How can i restrict not to auto populate these details? I want that if user fills email id then only saved password shall populate otherwise those fields should remain empty.

Comment: `"But i do not want to auto populate these details"` - Then don't click "Yes" when the browser asks you?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: How about setting `autocompleted="off"` for input elements?

Comment: I hope you don't really use that field for the passwords and, in fact, you use `type="password"`

Comment: why -1 ??? its not me .. if user click to save the password then how can i handle..

Comment: It is not for you to decide if someone wants their browser to auto-populate input fields in a form. You should never break browser features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form name="checkform" action="example.php" autocomplete='off'>
   <input type="text" id="c_email" name="c_email" placeholder="EMail here">
   <input type="text" id="c_epass" name="c_epass" placeholder="Password here">
   <input type="submit" id="c_sub">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `autocomplete="off"` in inputbox:

```
<form name="checkform" action="example.php" autocomplete="off">
   <input type="text" id="c_email" name="c_email" placeholder="EMail here">
   <input type="text" id="c_epass" name="c_epass" placeholder="Password here">
   <input type="submit" id="c_sub">
</form>
```

[Reference is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion).